# Implement a global queue data structure in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, global-variables

I have a Ruby on Rails app in which I need to maintain a queue of ids. I tried using a global array as a queue but then read that global variables in web apps stop being global if multiple instance of my app run. How can I then maintain an application wide queue?

Here's how my ApplicationController looks:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :update_queue, :get_next_free_agent
  $agent_queue = []
  def update_queue(agent)
    if agent.status == "AVAILABLE"
        if agent_queue.find_index(agent.reg_id) == nil
            $agent_queue.push(agent.reg_id)
        end
    else
        $agent_queue.delete(agent.reg_id)
    end
  end

  def get_next_free_agent
    return agent_queue.shift
  end
end
```

Neither does this work, nor do I want to use it any more after reading about how global variables area bad idea. Please provide an alternate solution.

Thanks.

Comment: As pointed out, any key-value store. Redis, Memcached etc.

Answer (score 1):

From afar it seems your problem could be solved by a Message Queue System like Resque.

If you don't wat to go down that route, store the array in a key-value store, that provides atomic pop and push on the array (like redis), this way you wont need to worry that only one process acesses the array